# Decompile jar file to use it as a project in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a jar file but not source code. I had some issue with this code which is not working as expected. So I want to decompile it use it as a project in intellij. Could you please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: Did you try finding a JAR file containing the sources? Also, are you using maven?

Answer (score 2):

You need a java decompiler, like jd-gui http://jd.benow.ca/

Comment: This is not necessary with the version 14.1 - "Now you don’t need any third-party plugins to take a look at what’s inside a library for which you don’t have the source code." http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/07/intellij-idea-14-eap-138-1029-is-out/

Answer (score 0):

use jd-gui and copy the source code in intellij. also normally with decomiplation your code will have multiple localobject and you have to deal with it